# Parse Javascript value in Python

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

Im currently on a project which requires a certain value to post, but this value is generated from the site.

it's called cipherValue and it looks like this:

```
{"CipherValue":"XhPXXMLJd5ai5iVPZPnoVf6vb9gARbngv3pw5JgfQQQ/KKMRErec5B9woMhtb6bRzT8jGR0zfSjqe2DZwKZesebpYCxL1kghE1h5AaMdteecCU1FJ3x/zcfWC9bLyAXIa3Oko8Y4hLZS2u6iv/fwPXoE7FNTyLDhkCmAsQa/Eq qQRnYkszCAGzDp2MVAN7WpAbBtjrguHyvPe6SRhAJIqMTdkvembsNSp7r7Vl8mCQZa yqIMtWpcfYcsWe6G vAtlDoUMDVP70dxAQGnWcXaHkfnT9rFpQJcmMJvKIhCJHYJO7fAfW a7JCNodc1oSrT9Lhkh4RIJEItGOieekIw"}
```

Here is JS of the site, sadly I have no JS knowledge that's why I have to provide you the full source.
https://workupload.com/file/J7Mbj8SY9uj

Here are some screenshots of the JS code:

[image: JS code 1]
[image: JS code 2]

Have a great Day!

Comment: Is that `'` at the end actually a `"`? If so, then this is JSON, and that's a pretty standard format to parse. If it actually is a `'` which doesn't match the opening `"`, you've got bigger problems since it's neither valid JSON nor valid JavaScript.

Comment: The website doesn't respond with the value, it generates from the JS code and sents a post request.

Comment: Also there is more values to post besides this value, I added it as an example.

Comment: Can you provide more context to the problem you're trying to solve? There are surely more viable options than parsing JavaScript code. Is the value generated by the JavaScript being posted to a Python server? If so, you could read the value instead. Are you trying to do HTML scraping perhaps?

Comment: I gone trough all requests to find this specific value, the issue here is I don't find it. There is not request that provides this value. I found this Chinese forum post where a user had the same issue: https://bbs.125.la/thread-14524656-1-1.html. I didn't really understood it.

Comment: Use debugger in browser, copy specific js code, and use `pyexecjs` to call it in python?